# ImportError: No module named 'django' when in virtualenv

Tags: python, django

new to python and django and getting the ImportError when I run python manage.py runserver.

I figured the problem was that django was not installed in the site_packages of the python version running in the virtualenv.  I ran the command under sudo "sudo python manage.py runserver" and it works.  So all is good.

Can someone explain to a noob what I did wrong in installing django or setting up the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to activate the virtual environment. Virtual environments never use the sudo command because nothing is being installed in the machines local library. To activate the virtual environment you open up terminal and type source /virtualenv/bin/activate.

Comment: I guess I wasn't starting the virtualenv correctly.  I was starting it via '. bin/activate'.  Running it with 'source ...' does it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Django inside the virtualenv.

sudo command will give you the global package so I guess django already installed in global.

Activate virtualenv then `pip install django` will resolve your issue.